# is there an idiomatic way to store and retrieve binary or text data as cassette tape audio?

Tags: audio, file-converter

For exploratory purposes, I'd like to try working with tape-based storage, and it seems like [compact audio cassettes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cassette_tape) would be a readily available piece of hardware to play with. I want to take binary or text data from a PC, transmit it through a 3.5mm audio cable to a tape recorder, record it to a cassette tape, and then be able to reverse the process to recover the original file. Lossless is a must, high storage density is nice to have.

The best thing I've found so far is [these](https://github.com/iffybooks/minimodem-zine) instructions, which use "minimodem", a software modem simulator. The idea is to 'save' a file by recording the modem noise it would make, and 'load' a file by playing that sound back in. Is there a better tool for this job?

I would like the host to be cross-platform, but if that is not possible, I can use Linux or Windows. A standalone application would be nice, but I would be satisfied with a python library or a command-line utility.

Comment: That show storage started.  It was not high density or reliable.  Is there a reason that you want to go back to futility.

Comment: I used to have one of those in the early 80s… wow, they could store entire *kilobytes* of data in mere minutes… and sometimes you could retrieve it uncompromised. They used special, expensive, data-grade cassettes; regular audio ones mainly didn't work.

Comment: This would be for educational purposes, not for intensive use. I was thinking maybe I could store a 20 kB text-based game on one, as a demonstration.

Comment: To add to @RohitGupta's comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commodore_Datasette - cassettes were a common data storage system for home computers back then.

Comment: Apparently the Famicom (the Japanese equivalent of the NES) had a cassette data storage system as well — https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Famicom_Data_Recorder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I can tell, the closest thing to a cassette data 'standard' is the [Kansas City Standard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kansas_City_standard), which sends one bit at a time at a rate of 300 bits per second. Out of every 12 byte envelope, 4 are used for tracking purposes, so the effective data rate is actually more like 200 bits per second. This is a really slow rate compared to what a cassette tape is actually capable of, so it didn't really catch on in the industry, and instead every computer had its own cassette format... but if you want an 'idiomatic' format, this is the closest there is to a standard. The Wikipedia article lists several common modifications made to increase the speed, but most of these are incompatible with one another and you would need a way to inform your user which decoding method to use.

A python script for working with the Kansas City Standard is available at https://github.com/gstrike/py-kcs.